# Wrong function address in array

Tags: function, assembly, dll, masm

I have this code in my .data section:

```
sort_list dq __imp_bubbleSort, __imp_insertionSort, __imp_quickSort, __imp_selectionSort, __imp_shakerSort
cur_sort dq 1
```

This functions I import from my dll:

```
extern __imp_bubbleSort:qword
extern __imp_shakerSort:qword
extern __imp_quickSort:qword
extern __imp_selectionSort:qword
extern __imp_insertionSort:qword
```

In function I tried to call this fucntions like this:

```
SortThread proc
local demmy:qword
sub rsp, stacksz
mov bSorting, 1
mov rcx, p_arr
mov rdx, arrsize
mov rax, cur_sort
mov rbx, sort_list
call qword ptr [rbx + rax * 8]
mov bSorting, 0
ret
SortThread endp
```

For [rbx+0 * 8] it's right my Bubble sort function, but for [rbx+1 * 8] I get wrong function, but this function also in my dll.. So it's firstly wrong adresses in my sort_list. Why? Feel free to tell me if need a functions code from dll.

Comment: If having trouble debugging something with a ~complex addressing mode, use an extra instruction with a free register, for example, for `call qword ptr [rbx + rax * 8]`, use `leaq rdi, [rbx + rax * 8]; call [rdi]`, then during debugging, after the `leaq`, you can see the address it is going to use in the next instruction.  Or for `mov rax, [rbx + rax * 8]`, use `leaq rdi, [rbx + rax * 8]; mov rax, [rdi]`.  Just a way to verify that it's doing what you think.

Comment: @ErikEidt: In Intel syntax, it's just `lea`, not `leaq`.  But yes, "wasting" instructions and a spare register can be useful as a sanity check for debugging, especially for people that aren't 100% sure they understand addressing-modes or how to get their debugger to compute an address from multiple registers to check memory there.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I made a little mess up with pointers. Now it works!

```
mov rbx, offset sort_list
mov rax, [rbx + rax * 8]
call qword ptr [rax]
```